# ConvertJSONToSql is looking for IS_AUTOINCREMENT

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, apache-nifi, hortonworks-sandbox

I use the ConvertJSONToSql to convert each Json flowfile to sql, however I keep on getting this error

```
Could not find IS_AUTOINCREMENT in [table_cat, table_schem, table_name, column_name, data_type, type_name, column_size, buffer_length, decimal_digits, num_prec_radix, nullable, remarks, column_def, sql_data_type, sql_datetime_sub, char_octet_length, ordinal_position, is_nullable, scope_catalog, scope_schema, scope_table, source_data_type, is_auto_increment]
```

I don't know the reason for this.  I just created my table in hive like the following:

```
create table ... 
... 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS TEXTFILE
```

Comment: It looks like there is a mis-match in the naming... the message is looking for "IS_AUTOINCREMENT" and the array of names has "is_auto_increment" with two underscores.

Comment: Sorry but i don't know where this is_autoincrement is. I mean when i create the table i dont have this column. So i have no idea about this mismatch.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the JSON that is going into ConvertJSONToSQL?

Comment: This flowfile comes from SplitJson processor

{"ID":8,"COL1":8,"COL2":867,"COL3":867,"COL4":"","COL5":""}

Answer (score 1):

This relates to [Hive-13528](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-13528). The JIRA description is copied below for completeness.

> As stated by the documentation, the return of getColumns() from DatabaseMetaData (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getColumns(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) should return a ResultSet with a few columns, including one named "IS_AUTOINCREMENT" used to describe if the attribute is auto increment.
>   However, in Hive implementation, the column is named "IS_AUTO_INCREMENT" (as stated in line 107 of file service/src/java/org/apache/hive/service/cli/operation/GetColumnsOperation.java).

Your options at this point are to wait for the Hive fix to roll out and apply it, or you could build your own nifi-standard-nar bundle with a modified ConvertJSONToSQL processor. The 'IS_AUTOINCREMENT' name is hardcoded in that processor.